# Running a swing application with older java version

Tags: java, swing, web, java-web-start

i have a swing application needs j2 se 7+. i want to run this application with java 1.6.10 installed computers. my ex application needs 1.6.10 so i cant update my jre to 1.7+, when i call the application from web, web start says "you must install j2s2 7+ to launch this application" how can i run this application with java 1.6?

```
 <J2se version ="1.7+"/>
```

Comment: *"my ex application needs 1.6.10"*  What the what?  You divorced it?  What does 'ex' mean here?

Comment: its my another application wich compiled for java 1.6

Comment: *"another application wich compiled for java 1.6"*  It should be able to run on a 1.6+ (which includes 1.7) JRE.  Try it.

Comment: decompile using jd-gui, save the sources, remove the version check, recompile

Answer (score 1):

Differences among different major versions of java (1.5 - 1.6 - 1.7) include differences at the compilation step.  Therefore if an application has been compiled for Java 1.7, you cannot run it on a Java 1.6 Virtual Machine.

In order to do what you want, you will need the source recompiled for Java 1.6.  If it can be compiled for 1.6, it is quite likely to run on 1.6 and 1.7.